# Customize deepview by adding a image to it based on link data

Tags: branch.io

I would like to customize my deepview with a specific image depending on where on my site it is clicked (custom product image for example).

I understand that I can not use javascript in the deepview but my thinking was that I might be able to pass a url to our cdn in the query parameters of the link but I can't figure out how to access it in the deepview.

Comment: Can you submit a ticket - https://help.branch.io/using-branch/page/submit-a-ticket? We should be able to whitelist your Deepview for JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks I have submitted a ticket for getting JS access and will update this question once I figure out how to do it.